# retrieve data from Oracle XMLType with multiple or matrix type text node values

Tags: oracle, xmltype

I'm very new to XML and I don't know how to extract XMLType from Oracle. My task is loop through a table column with XMLType datatype (please see attached imaged file) and check the length of value of text node. However, one type of text node is different from the other. One has multiple values separated with ';' and another is by matrix with multiple items and multiple records. I cannot even go pass this simple SQL statement that returns null vale:

```
 SELECT extract( xs.xs_xml, '/arg0/item/text()' )
 FROM   XML_Shield xs
 WHERE  xs_id = 521521;
```

Looking in the internet for solution similar to my task but none fits my requirement. Most of the examples I see are one value text nodes and not matrix. I must admit this is out of my deep.

Can you guys please help me? I appreciate your assistance regarding this matter.

thanks...

Comment: Could you post an example of your XML? I'm not sure what you mean by "matrix", it's not an XML term I'm familiar with.

Comment: i don't think it's actually an XML term at all but that's what we call them. Sorry for the confusion. It looks like a nested table inside a table. I can't post the XML example in here as it exceeds the maximum number of charcters for the comments. but I can send it to you by email if that helps.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your post above to add more information, that's how people normally do it.

Comment: here's the XML file I'm dealing with:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UT32"?>
 <S:Env xmlns:S="http://soap.org/">
  <S:Body>
   <ns2:request xmlns:ns2="http://ris.com/">
    <arg0>
     <item>
      <name>MATRIX</name>
      <value><![CDATA[<Matrix ver="1">
       <Items>
        <item id="i1" name="Code"/>
        <item id="i2" name="Date"/>
       </Items>
       <Cords>
        <Cord no="1">
         <Value itemId="i1">ZW</Value>
         <Value itemId="i2">2016-03-22</Value>
        </Cord>
       </Cords>
      </Matrix>
      ]]></value>
     </item>
    </arg0>
   </ns2:request>
  </S:Body>
 </S:Env>